# Loading data when the scroll reaches top of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Iam using infinte scroll for pagination.The data is loading only when the scroller reaches the bottom of the page while using below code

```js
`$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        //Run the ajax call or other here
    }
});`
```

I want to load data when scroller reaches the top of my footer div

Comment: Minus the height of your footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() -  your footer div height
```